# Calculating the derivatives of an integral expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function:

```
ee[x, y] = Integrate[x^2 + y^2, x]
```

I want to calculate the derivatives of this function w.r.t `x` and `y`. For example:

```
D[ee[x, y], {1, 0}] //FullSimplify
```

But the result of mathematica (with or without using 'FullSimplify') is the input expression itself:

```
D[(x^3/3 + x*y^2)[x, y], {1, 0}]
```

I was wondering if anyone can explain how can I simplify the above expression

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be defined with patterns for the arguments

```
Clear[ee]

ee[x_, y_] = Integrate[x^2 + y^2, x]

(* x^3/3 + x y^2 *)
```

The derivatives are

```
D[ee[x, y], #] & /@ {x, y}

(* {x^2 + y^2, 2 x y} *)
```

More simply,

```
D[ee[x, y], {{x, y}}]

(* {x^2 + y^2, 2 x y} *)
```

Or more obscurely,

```
(Derivative @@ #)[ee][x, y] & /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}

(* {x^2 + y^2, 2 x y} *)
```

Or if you mean to take the derivatives in turn

```
D[ee[x, y], x, y]

(* 2 y *)

D[ee[x, y], y, x]

(* 2 y *)
```

Comment: And what if my real code is such a way that ee[x,y] is first used in an expression (e.g. named 'hh') without definition with ee[x_,y_] then I am substituting an integral expression for ee[x,y] and then calculating the derivative? @Bob-Hanlon

Comment: `D[expr /. ee[x_, y_] :> Integrate[x^2 + y^2, x], {{x, y}}]`???? To clarify your intent give a specific example, what you have tried, and explain the problem you are having.